# Ubuntu server 14.04 postgres Tainted

Tags: postgresql, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I run an Ubuntu 14.04 server, on which Postgresql 9.3 is installed. I am seeing kernel messages flooding kern.log and syslog, hundreds of lines a minute, until the server is out of free space. I'm at a loss at to what is causing this.

In the past, I have resolved it temporarily by updating to the newest kernel and rebooting, but the problem soon returns. I would appreciate some help?

Below is one of the log entries:

```
Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554606] ------------[ cut here ]------------

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554620] WARNING: CPU: 31 PID: 29156 at /build/linux-hFNI9K/linux-3.13.0/net/core/dst.c:285 dst_release+0x45/0x60()

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554621] Modules linked in: ppdev vmw_balloon coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lr
w gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd serio_raw vmwgfx ttm drm vmw_vmci i2c_piix4 parport_pc lp shpchp mac_hid parport psmouse mptspi mptscsih vmxnet3 mptbase pata_ac
pi floppy

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554640] CPU: 31 PID: 29156 Comm: postgres Tainted: G        W     3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu
Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554642] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/30/2014

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554643]  0000000000000009 ffff88081207bb18 ffffffff81723cc0 0000000000000000
Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554648]  ffff88081207bb50 ffffffff8106785d ffff88080e485500 00000000fffffffe

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554651]  ffff880810c58cc0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff88081207bb60

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554654] Call Trace:

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554661]  [<ffffffff81723cc0>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554665]  [<ffffffff8106785d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554667]  [<ffffffff8106793a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554669]  [<ffffffff81630045>] dst_release+0x45/0x60

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554673]  [<ffffffff81610cf1>] sk_dst_check+0xb1/0xe0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554678]  [<ffffffff816c3d1f>] ip6_sk_dst_lookup_flow+0x2f/0x1b0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554682]  [<ffffffff816ded3e>] udpv6_sendmsg+0x61e/0xb10

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554688]  [<ffffffff81246eea>] ? ext4_da_write_end+0xba/0x250

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554694]  [<ffffffff8114f917>] ? generic_file_buffered_write+0x187/0x250

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554699]  [<ffffffff81696064>] inet_sendmsg+0x64/0xb0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554704]  [<ffffffff81314c07>] ? apparmor_socket_sendmsg+0x17/0x20

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554707]  [<ffffffff8160e84b>] sock_sendmsg+0x8b/0xc0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554710]  [<ffffffff8123c322>] ? ext4_file_write+0xa2/0x3f0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554714]  [<ffffffff813398c8>] ? generic_make_request+0x18/0x110

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554719]  [<ffffffff8172fe74>] ? __do_page_fault+0x204/0x570

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554721]  [<ffffffff8160ed91>] SYSC_sendto+0x121/0x1c0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554727]  [<ffffffff811c0991>] ? __sb_end_write+0x31/0x60

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554730]  [<ffffffff811be502>] ? vfs_write+0x192/0x1f0

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554732]  [<ffffffff8160f77e>] SyS_sendto+0xe/0x10

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554735]  [<ffffffff8173489d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554736] ---[ end trace 38c082ce448557d2 ]---

Sep 28 15:47:32 database kernel: [430051.554737] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

This has happened when I was running the database on a physical machine, and now when it is in a VM on ESX 5.1.

These are some details about the VM:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3, x86_64
Kernel: 3.13.0-63-generic
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz, 32 cores
```

Comment: Similar https://github.com/openstreetmap/operations/issues/29 . Kernel bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with Ubuntu 16.04 and Postgresql 9.6

Disabling ipv6 solved the issue.

```
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment out the ipv6 lines in /etc/hosts

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1    localhost       ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#ff02::1        ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2        ip6-allrouters
```

Make Postgres listen **only** on ipv4 and replace localhost by 127.0.0.1

Now restart postgres

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: This has solved the problem But what is the real reason behind disabling the ivp6?